# Does default _id_ index use by mongoquery?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

Let's assume, we have mongo collection mentioned as below

db.test.findOne()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d0313dc62b629cfabe22ff"), "a" : 1, "b" : 1, "c" : 1 }

and this collection has more than million records.

now, if i want to find out records with condition as field "a" greater then 1000 and "b" field less than 9000
then my mongo query could be like ..

db.test.find({'a':{'$gt':1000}, 'b':{'$lt': 9000}}, {'a':1, 'c':1})
and to make above search faster, i have already applied compound index on "a" & "b" field.
and it been used by above query ..

now, here as you must aware, all the collection come with default index on "**_*id*_**" field for primary key.

does my above mongo query used default index "**_*id*_**" ? if yes then how ? and if not then why ?

thanks you
javaamtho

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  You already say the query is using the compound index you created, not the index on `_id`.

Comment: Use `explain` to determine what indexes are being used. `_id`'s index wouldn't be used if it's not specified in you query.

Comment: @JohnnyHK yes .using explain(), i am able to see that my compound index is being used but does mongo use default _id_ index too for some purpose ? how can i see more than two index usages if my mongo engine used it internally ? my question is tricky but how you get it now ..

Comment: @javaamtho MongoDB never uses more than one index per query.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, mongo does not use the default index on _id with your query, because _id does not occur in the condition nor in the sorting of your query.

Comment: thanks ..so in sort query like db.test.find({'a':{'$gt':1000}, 'b':{'$lt': 9000}}, {'a':1, 'c':1}).sort({b:1}) ..it wont use it ?

Comment: No, the default index is only used if you use "_id" either in the condition or in the sort object. I.e. if you search an document with a certain _id: db.test.find({_id:my_certain_id}) would use the default index.

Comment: If you think my answer is right, please accept it. You could read more here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes/

Comment: @heinob: would you have a look at a similar question at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115444/when-is-the-id-index-used?

Comment: I guess that it should be marked as the right question.